# Clojure Macro Expansion

Tags: macros, clojure, lisp

I am working on a macro, I am trying to figure out how to avoid expansion of certain forms, take the following and macro for example,

```
(defmacro and
  ([] true)
  ([x] x)
  ([x & next]
   `(let [and# ~x]
      (if and# (and ~@next) and#))))
```

When expanded,

```
(mexpand-all '(and 1 2 3))
```

becomes,

```
(let* [and__973__auto__ 1]
      (if and__973__auto__
        (let* [and__973__auto__ 2]
              (if and__973__auto__ 3 and__973__auto__))
        and__973__auto__))
```

In this case what I need to do is stop let from expanding into let*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recursive macro-expansion works by repeatedly expanding the form until there is no macro to expand. That means that if you want to recursively expand a macro, but ignore certain forms, you'll have to either code your own custom expander, or find someone else's.

Here's a quick example:

```
(defn my-expander [form]
    (cond (not (list? form)) (mexpand-1 form)
        (= (first form) 'let) form
           :else (map my-expander (mexpand-1 form))))
```

Please forgive me if I made any mistakes. I'm much stronger with Scheme and CL than Clojure.

--Edit--
Note that the above function will not expand the subforms of a let statement, either.

Answer (score 5):

Huh? It's not clear what you mean by "stop" `let` from expanding. `let` is a macro defined in clojure.core, which the compiler knows nothing about: it only understands `let*`. If your macro expanded into a `let` which (somehow) refused to expand further, it would fail to compile.

If you want to inspect just the output of your macro in isolation, without worrying about recursively expanding it, you should use `macroexpand` or `macroexpand-1` instead of this `mexpand-all` thing. I don't know where `mexpand-all` comes from, but when I need something like that I use `clojure.walk/macroexpand-all`.

Comment: What I am trying to do is recursively expand everything except the let form. BTW, mexpand comes from contrib macro-utils

Comment: I too am trying to prevent certain forms from expanding. I'd like to provide an explanation for why that problem has a right to exist. In my case I am trying to use clojure macro expansion as a transpiler from a non-clojure lisp to yet another non-clojure lisp. It works quite well except for some corner cases where the source lisp syntax clashes with the clojure's built-in macros.

Answer (score 1):

Use `macroexpand-1` to perform a single level of macro expansion.

After loading your `and` macro, this expression:

```
user=> (macroexpand-1 '(and 1 2 3))
```

Yields:

```
(clojure.core/let [and__1__auto__ 1] (if and__1__auto__ (clojure.core/and 2 3) and__1__auto__))
```